# Custom Python extension - Import error: undefined symbol

Tags: python, c, python-3.x

Learning how to write a C extension in Python. Running into the following error when executing `ptest.py`

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ptest.py", line 1, in <module>
    import euler_py as eul
ImportError: /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/euler_py.cpython-
36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so: undefined symbol: problem_one
```

I'm assuming this is some type of linking issue.

## setup.py

```
sources = glob.glob('ext/*.c')

euler = Extension(
    'euler_py',
    include_dirs=['src'],
    sources=sources,
    extra_compile_args=['-std=c99']
)

setup(
    name='euler_py',
    version='0.1',
    description='Project Euler Solutions',
    ext_modules=[euler]
)
```

## ptest.py

```
import euler_py as eul

print(eul.problem_one(10))
```

The underlying functions are in `/src` and I wrote `test.c` to test purely in C. My extension is in `/ext/euler_py.c` shown below

## ext/euler_py.c

```
#include <Python.h>
#include "../src/euler.h"

static char module_docstring[] = "Provides interface to Project Euler problems";

/*
 * Function implementations
 */


static PyObject* euler_py_problem_one(PyObject *self, PyObject *args)
{
    int max, result;

    if (!PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "i", &max))
        return NULL;

    result = problem_one(max);

    return Py_BuildValue("i", result);
}
// END function implementations

// Wire in functions to module
static PyMethodDef module_methods[] = {
        {"problem_one", euler_py_problem_one, METH_VARARGS, "Solution to problem 1"},
        {NULL, NULL, 0, NULL}
};


// Module definition
static struct PyModuleDef euler_py_module = {
        PyModuleDef_HEAD_INIT,
        "euler_py",
        module_docstring,
        -1,
        module_methods
};

// Module initialization function
PyMODINIT_FUNC PyInit_euler_py(void)
{
    return PyModule_Create(&euler_py_module);
}
```

Repo is [here](https://github.com/Amertz08/euler_py). I've played around with `library_dirs` & `include_dirs` on the `Extension()` initiation and no luck. Python version 3.6. Need a second look.

**EDIT**

Repo linked to has changed since original ask. Added linking for other 3 functions in the same manor as previous.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forget to include all source files:

```
sources = glob.glob('ext/*.c') + glob.glob('src/*.c')
```

you could see c extension build detail with `setup.py build -fv`:

```
$ python setup.py build -fv
...
clang -bundle -undefined dynamic_lookup build/temp.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.6/ext/euler_py.o build/temp.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.6/src/euler.o build/temp.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.6/src/helpers.o -o build/lib.macosx-10.13-x86_64-3.6/euler_py.cpython-36m-darwin.so
```

now `helpers.o` and `euler.o` properly linked.

Comment: So can I get rid of the `include_dirs` or no because thats how they find the `.h` files?

Comment: @Adam I think it depends. if you write `#include <euler.h>` or `#include "euler.h"`, you need `include_dirs`; if you use `#include "../src/euler.h"` then you don't. I prefer former version. [read more about #include](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/preprocessor/include)

Comment: Yeah I think my IDE automatically put the relative import in there (CLion) I also prefer simply `"euler.h"` vs `"../src/euler.h"`

Comment: errata: correct c #include reference link is http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/preprocessor/include

Comment: Ok thank you. I'll give you the 50 pts when it allows me. Apparently I have to wait 20 hrs.

Comment: Also how much experience do you have writing C extensions for python? I am trying to add that to my skillset.